# Can we search 2 strings which has to be in a same line in NotePad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search for strings in notepad++ which has strings "XYZ" and "ERROR" in the same line.

I've tried to search with XYZ.*ERROR but the issue is that it returns the lines with only ERROR,only XYZ, and both XYZ and ERROR.

Eg: My records look somewhat like this:

```
The application XYZ has a ERROR
XYZ is a good application
The application WXYZ has a ERROR
ERROR in server
```

Now when I search, I want only line 1 to be returned in the search result. However, I am getting every line in the search which defeats the purpose.

Comment: On my PC the search done with regex enabled does match only line 1, so XYZ.*ERROR is a correct search pattern. Pretty simple one. Unless XYZ or ERROR is persent for other resons in the text

Answer (score 2):

Insert word boundaries around your keywords:

```
\bXYZ\b.*\bERROR\b
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I would expect `XYZ.*ERROR` to work too... is this a `. matches newline` issue?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5: `XYZ.*ERROR` matches `WXYZ has a ERROR` but it shouldn't

Comment: ah, fair point - I'd missed that part but I wouldn't expect `XYZ.*ERROR` to match 'every line' as per the question?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5: As said in question: `I want only line 1 to be returned in the search result.`

Comment: Yes but you also said 'I am getting every line in the search' so I was confused.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5: I didn't say anything, I'm not OP ;)

Comment: I wish I could edit old comments... sorry!

Yes but **the question** also said 'I am getting every line in the search' so I was confused.

Comment: UPDATE: I am new to using Notepad++ hence didn't understand .* command.
I tried using it again and it worked perfectly well... Can someone explain "\b" command? What does it do?

Comment: @IrfanBasha: `\b` is called “word boundary”, it's a zero-length assertion that match a boundary between a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html